# Rails method instead of id in model's has_many

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Somewhere in my model I have:

```
  has_many :custom_values, -> { where(custom_field: CustomField.where(field_format: "company"))}, :foreign_key => "value", :primary_key => :id_s, :dependent => :destroy
  def id_s
    read_attribute(:id).to_s
  end
```

`custom_value.value` is varchar so I'm trying to make string from `id` with method `id_s`

But it doesn't work, it allways compare `custom_value.value` to `NULL`

FE:

```
2.5.0 :037 > WkAccount.first().custom_values
  WkAccount Load (0.7ms)  SELECT  `wk_accounts`.* FROM `wk_accounts`  ORDER BY `wk_accounts`.`id` ASC LIMIT 1
  CustomValue Load (36.5ms)  SELECT `custom_values`.* FROM `custom_values` WHERE `custom_values`.`value` = NULL AND `custom_values`.`custom_field_id` IN (SELECT `custom_fields`.`id` FROM `custom_fields` WHERE `custom_fields`.`field_format` = 'company')
```

while:

```
2.5.0 :039 > WkAccount.first().id_s
  WkAccount Load (1.2ms)  SELECT  `wk_accounts`.* FROM `wk_accounts`  ORDER BY `wk_accounts`.`id` ASC LIMIT 1
 => "7"
```

I can't figure out, why is there

```
WHERE `custom_values`.`value` = NULL
```

Instead of

```
WHERE `custom_values`.`value` = "5"
```

Any idea?

**EDIT:** added whole model

```
class WkAccount < ActiveRecord::Base
  unloadable
  belongs_to :address, :class_name => 'WkAddress', :dependent => :destroy
  has_many :billable_projects, as: :parent, class_name: "WkAccountProject", :dependent => :destroy
  has_many :invoices, as: :parent, class_name: "WkInvoice", :dependent => :restrict_with_error
  has_many :invoice_items, through: :invoices
  has_many :custom_values, -> { where(custom_field: CustomField.where(field_format: "company"))}, :foreign_key => "value", :primary_key => "id_s", :dependent => :destroy
  has_many :projects, through: :billable_projects
  has_many :contracts, as: :parent, class_name: "WkContract", :dependent => :destroy
  has_many :opportunities, as: :parent, class_name: "WkOpportunity", :dependent => :destroy
  has_many :activities, as: :parent, class_name: 'WkCrmActivity', :dependent => :destroy
  has_many :contacts, foreign_key: "account_id", class_name: "WkCrmContact", :dependent => :destroy
  has_many :payments, as: :parent, class_name: "WkPayment"
  belongs_to :location, :class_name => 'WkLocation'
  validates_presence_of :name
  validate :hasAnyValues

  def id_s
    read_attribute(:id).to_s
  end

  def hasAnyValues
    name.blank? && address_id.blank? && activity_id.blank? && industry.blank? && annual_revenue.blank? && assigned_user_id.blank? && id.blank?
  end

  # Returns account's contracts for the given project
  # or nil if the account do not have contract
  def contract(project)
    contract = nil
    unless project.blank?
        contract = contracts.where(:project_id => project.id).first
        contract = contracts[0] if contract.blank?
    end
    contract
  end

end
```

Comment: Please provide you models code so we can help.

Answer (score 0):

From the [docs](https://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#options-for-belongs-to-primary-key):

> By convention, Rails assumes that the `id` column is used to hold the primary key of its tables. The `:primary_key` option allows you to specify a different *column*.

That said, you simply cannot associate records by custom methods. You have to associate them by columns in the database. That means if you need the return value of the `id_s` string to associate records then add a column to your table and use that column instead of a custom method.

Comment: >That said, you simply cannot associate records by custom methods.
God damn, I thank that it's possible and spend plenty of time on looking for a way to accomplish this. 
>That means if you need the return value of the id_s string to associate records then add a column to your table and use that column instead of a custom method.
I have no other option then.
However it sounds like a waste of space to make additional column that would only store ids but as a varchars...

Comment: Why do you store then in two different formats in the two tables in the first place?